# Continuous Boyce Index (CBI) in R

Tags: r, machine-learning

I am predicting species' environmental suitability scores. To do so, I make use of the *caret* package and run classification problems. The literature advocates for the use of the continuous Boyce index (CBI) as a performance measure for model reliability (see 1). I currently tune the models to maximize AUC not the CBI. Nonetheless, I obtain perfect CBI scores (correlation of 1), for both the training and testing data, using *ecospat::ecospat.boyce* as well as the *adamlilith/enmSdm::contBoyce2x* available via rdrr.io.

I am not sure whether I am making a mistake and input the wrong vectors. The relevant logistic regression output looks something like this:

```
head(lg$pred)
      pred      obs   absence  presence rowIndex parameter Resample
1 presence  absence 0.4144518 0.5855482        1      none    Fold1
2 presence presence 0.4402172 0.5597828        2      none    Fold1
3 presence presence 0.3647270 0.6352730        3      none    Fold1
4  absence  absence 0.7154779 0.2845221        6      none    Fold1
5 presence presence 0.1574952 0.8425048        9      none    Fold1
6 presence presence 0.0146231 0.9853769       10      none    Fold1
```

I call the functions as follows

**Ecospat::ecospat.boyce**

fit = A vector or Raster-Layer containing the predicted suitability values

obs = A vector containing the predicted suitability values or xy-coordinates (if "fit" is a Raster-Layer) of the validation points (presence records)

```
ecospat::ecospat.boyce(fit=lg$pred$presence,obs=lg$pred$presence[lg$pred$obs=="presence"],PEplot=T)
```

[image]

**adamlilith/enmSdm::contBoyce2x**

pres = Numeric vector. Predicted values at presence sites.

bg = Numeric vector.  Predicted values at absence/background sites.

```
contBoyce2x(pres=lg$pred$presence[lg$pred$obs=="presence"],bg=lg$pred$presence[lg$pred$obs=="absence"],graph=T)
```

[image]

Have I understood the input arguments correctly? Is it possible to obtain a perfect CBI score without even trying to tune the models to maximize this metric?

*(1) Hirzel, A.H., Le Lay, G., Helfer, V., Randin, C., Guisan, A. (2006). Evaluating the ability of the habitat suitability models to predict species presences. Ecological Modelling 199, 142-152.*

Comment: I'm not familiar with the ecospat function so much, but I wrote contBoyce2X and contBoyce  in enmSdm. I agree it's good to be suspicious, but it appears you're doing everything right here.

Comment: Note that there are two ways to interpret how Hirzel et al describe how to calculate CBI... you can divided the space into bins that overlap such that most points are covered twice (e.g., bins like 0-0.1, 0.05-0.15, 0.1-0.2, ...) which is what contBoyce2X does. You can also divide it into bins that overlap points multiple times, like 0-0.01, 0.01-0.11, 0.02-0.12, etc. The contBoyce in enmSdm does this. There are known differences between these functions in enmSdm and ecospat (see the help for contBoyce in enmSdm for an example). In practice, the differences are very minor (~0.02 or so)

Comment: Thanks for your response! Good to know I have not made a careless mistake. I will look further into what could cause the ideal scores

Comment: @Eden, I wonder if sample size can have an importance on differences between `contBoyce` and `contBoyce2x`? I tried both functions, on a species with a very low sample size, and where the map is visually correct (I have 17 presence points, all in high suitability classes). The `contBoyce2x` gives a positive CBI (0.83), whereas the `contBoyce` gives a negative CBI (-0.67),  despite the fact that 15 out of 17 presence points have suitabilities above 0.97.

Comment: @Boris I've seen the same issue with CBI--it's very sensitive to the exact data you use (statistically, it has low bias but high variance). CBI does tell you how different the occurrences are from the background, so if your model predicts high suitability in a lot of places, CBI could be low. BTW, the ecospat version of CBI gives nearly the same values (there's some difference in how that function handles duplicate values I don't understand), so the problem isn't relegated to `contBoyce` or `contBoyce2X`. The problem is more with CBI. - Adam Smith

Comment: Thanks a lot Adam. Probably, this is something to explore in the near future, because CBI remains one of the only indices available to asses the quality of presence-only models. Maybe, there is some room of improvement in the method itself - keeping the original idea of Hirzel et al. but trying new ways of implementation.

Regardless, I found consistent differences between `contBoyce` and `contBoyce2X`, and I also feel it could be useful to see the advantages/inconvenients of both implementation, in order to provide guidelines to choose. 

So many things to explore, so little time! ;)

Comment: It is probaly to late for you, but in case anybody else comes across the same problem (like me) I found some interesting thoughts on the boyce index ( link to discussion: https://groups.google.com/g/maxent/c/raPasq0vy2s). One user says: "Usually you would want to calculate CBI using predictions at test presences. You can also calculate CBI for predictions at training presences, but it will probably give you an overestimate of how well the model performs." When I used my test data instead of all my presence points the CBI dropped from 0.99 to 0.93.